# Arranging $\mathbb N$ into a two-dimensional array to prove a countably infinite collection of countable sets is countable.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, infinity, natural-numbers

If $A_n$ is a countable set for each $n \in\mathbb N,$ then $$\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$$ is countable. How does arranging the natural numbers in a two-dimensional array allow one to show the statement given in the title?

Is it that, given any set $A_i$, being countably infinite, is in bijection with the $i$-th row of that two-dimensional array, itself being countably infinite, and therefore the collection of the sets $A_i$ is in the bijection with the set of rows in that two-dimensional array, which of course is in bijection with the natural numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since each $A_n$ is countable, there exists, for each $n$, a bijective function $f_n : \mathbb N \to A_n$.

Using these $f_n$'s, we can define a function $f : \mathbb N \times \mathbb N \to \cup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$, which sends each $(n, m) \in \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$ to the element $f_n(m) \subset A_n\subset \bigcup_{n = 1}^\infty A_n$. Clearly, this function $f$ is surjective.

So we have exhibited a surjective function $f$ from the countable set $\mathbb N \times \mathbb N$ onto the set $\bigcup_{n = 1}^\infty A_n$. Hence $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$ is countable.

[The set $\mathbb N \times \mathbb N$ in this answer is the "two-dimensional array" referred to in your hint.]

Comment: It probably deserves to be noted that you need the axiom of choice (or some variant of it) to be able to decide on all of the $f_n$s at the same time such that you can use them to construct a single function $\mathbb N\times\mathbb N\to\bigcup_n A_n$.

Comment: What do you mean by this? And why? The "Axiom of Choice" and the "Axiom of Completeness" are, of course, two different axiomatic statements? Thank you!

Comment: The statement "Using these $f_n$'s...." implicitly assumes Choice... WHICH $f_n$'s??? What we know is that for each $n$ the set $S_n$ of bijections from $\Bbb N$ to  $A_n$  is not empty. The axiom of Choice is needed to prove that there exists a function $g:\Bbb N\to \cup_{n\in \Bbb N}S_n$ such that $\forall n\;(g(n)\in S_n).$ So for any such $g$ we can re-name $g(n)$ as $ f_n$, so as to conclude that there exists a sequence $(f_n)_{n\in \Bbb N} $ where$ f_n\in S_n$ for every $n.$

Answer (score 0):

I think the two-dimensional array refers to something like this:
1 3 6 10 15 ...
2 5 9 14 ...
4 8 13 ...
7 12...
11 ...

In this case, you can call each column $C_i$. And $B_i$ is referred to the set of $A_i \backslash \bigcup_{k = 1}^{i-1} A_k$It is not hard to prove that $C_i$ is countable. Then there exists a bijective function $f_i: C_i \rightarrow B_i$. Notice that the $C_i$s are disjoint and $B_i$s are disjoint. Besides, each $B_i$ is also countable as they are subsets of $A_i$. If you combine these functions $f_i$ to a new function $f$, you will notice that the domain is $\mathbb{N}$ and the codomain is the union of all $A_i$, and the function is bijective.

(This is my first time answering a question on StackExchange, my writing style still needs a lot of improvement, but hope you would find this solution helpful!)